# Possible to use Camel's XSLT component with dynamic templates?

Tags: apache-camel

By dynamic templates, I don't mean a dynamic URI.  I mean the template itself which is assembled from pieces sitting in a database, transformed in various ways, has images inserted into it, etc.  All this is done within my Camel Routes. The finished XSLT template is sitting in an exchange property and now I want to run the message body XML through that XSLT.

Unlike the XQuery component which provides a lot of flexibility, it seems that the template file must come from only an external source with the XSLT component. Am I forced to write it out as a file first?

Answer (score 0):

Set the option `contentCache=false` then the template is re-read on each message. Then it can load eg from a file, where you can then update the file with new content as you want.

To add support for using bean or ref as the resource, so you can call a bean etc, is currently not supported but I logged a ticket so we will add that in a future release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11514

Comment: The option of using a bean or value from a Simple expression would definitely make life easier!  What about using a custom URIResolver?  It can return the source from anywhere, no?  I'm thinking something like `return new StreamSource(new StringReader(myBean.myXslCode));`

Comment: If you use one of the latest then the bean may already be supported, I cannot remember exactly which version it was added. Yes you can always use a custom URIResolver and implement your own logic. But keep the content cache as false so the resolver is used for each message

Comment: The version I'm currently using is 2.19.0, I'll take a look. If not, I'll try the URIResolver route.  Thanks for the info about `contentCache=false`.  I know for sure that would have messed me up later!